# How does numel work in adding zeroes to change the dimension of a vector in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I am trying to add two vectors; however, they do not have the same dimensions. For example only (since the one I am doing have 1000+ values), the vectors are:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5];
b = [1 2];
```

Since they do not have the same dimensions, I want to simply add zeroes to vector `b` to match the dimension of vector `a`.

Using the code `b(numel(a)) = 0;` I was able to do it. However, I am quite confused on how it worked as I only saw this code on the internet. I know that `numel(a)` is equal to 5, but I don't know how that code was able to add zeroes after `1 2` in variable `b` to match the dimension of variable `a`.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2):

When you set `b(5) = 0`, matlab can not simply leave the intervening elements `b(3:4)` unfilled, so they get zeros. If you did `b(numel(a)) = 1`, the intervening elements would still be filled with zero.

Keep in mind that this is a short cut that only works if you know for that fact that `b` is shorter than `a`. If not, you will be setting an element of `b` to 0, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: A more generic and explicit way to fill `b` would be `b(end+1:numel(a)) = 0;`

Comment: Note user16372530 code which is safe for the case where b is the same length as a. The original posted code is not safe for this case. Neither will work for the case where the length of b is greater than the length of a, but maybe this case doesn't need to be covered?